# Don't know how to generate sampling locations:

Tags: niftynet

How are the dimensions generated in the uniform sampler? I tried debugging the image size it seems it works for some of the iterations it does not for others. Any idea how to fix this. My configuration is given below :

[CUSTOM]

- num_classes: 14
- output_prob: True
- label_normalisation: True
- softmax: True
- min_sampling_ratio: 0
- compulsory_labels: (0, 1)
- rand_samples: 0
- min_numb_labels: 1
- proba_connect: True
- evaluation_units: foreground
- image: ('images',)
- label: ('label',)
- weight: ()
- sampler: ()
- inferred: ()

name: net_segment

[CONFIG_FILE]

- path: /home/ubuntu/niftynet/extensions/deepmedic/deepmedic_all_task_renambed_labels.ini

[IMAGES]

- csv_file:
- path_to_search: /home/ubuntu/med_deacthalon/Task_all_same_names/imagesTr_1
- filename_contains: ()
- filename_not_contains: ('*lung*',)
- interp_order: 3
- loader: None
- pixdim: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
- axcodes: ('A', 'R', 'S')
- spatial_window_size: (51, 51, 51)

[LABEL]

-csv_file:

- path_to_search: /home/ubuntu/med_deacthalon/Task_all_same_names/labelsTr_1
- filename_contains: ()
- filename_not_contains: ('*lung*',)
- interp_order: 3
- loader: None
- pixdim: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
- axcodes: ('A', 'R', 'S')
- spatial_window_size: (9, 9, 9)

[SYSTEM]

- cuda_devices: ""
- num_threads: 2
- num_gpus: 1
- model_dir: /home/ubuntu/models_nifty/deepmedic/all_task_same_name_rename_labels
- dataset_split_file: ./dataset_split.csv
- action: train

[NETWORK]

- name: deepmedic
- activation_function: relu
- batch_size: 32
- decay: 0.0
- reg_type: L2
- volume_padding_size: (21, 21, 21)
- volume_padding_mode: minimum
- window_sampling: uniform
- queue_length: 128
- multimod_foreground_type: and
- histogram_ref_file: histogram_standardisation_alltask.txt
- norm_type: percentile
- cutoff: (0.01, 0.99)
- foreground_type: otsu_plus
- normalisation: False
- whitening: True
- normalise_foreground_only: True
- weight_initializer: he_normal
- bias_initializer: zeros
- keep_prob: 1.0
- weight_initializer_args: {}
- bias_initializer_args: {}

[TRAINING]

- optimiser: adam
- sample_per_volume: 32
- rotation_angle: (-10.0, 10.0)
- rotation_angle_x: ()
- rotation_angle_y: ()
- rotation_angle_z: ()
- scaling_percentage: (-10.0, 10.0)
- random_flipping_axes: -1
- do_elastic_deformation: False
- num_ctrl_points: 4
- deformation_sigma: 15
- proportion_to_deform: 0.5
- lr: 0.001
- loss_type: Dice
- starting_iter: 0
- save_every_n: 45
- tensorboard_every_n: 20
- max_iter: 10
- max_checkpoints: 20
- validation_every_n: -1
- validation_max_iter: 1
- exclude_fraction_for_validation: 0.0
- exclude_fraction_for_inference: 0.0

[INFERENCE]

- spatial_window_size: (57, 57, 57)
- inference_iter: -1
- dataset_to_infer:
- save_seg_dir: ./deepmedic/alltask_newname
- output_postfix: _niftynet_out
- output_interp_order: 0
- border: (36, 36, 36)

`CRITICAL:niftynet: Don't know how to generate sampling locations: Spatial dimensions of the grouped input sources are not consistent. {(477, 451, 187), (391, 369, 147)}
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/niftynet/NiftyNet/niftynet/engine/image_window_buffer.py", line 148, in _push
    for output_dict in self():
  File "/home/ubuntu/niftynet/NiftyNet/niftynet/engine/sampler_uniform.py", line 81, in layer_op
    self.window.n_samples)
  File "/home/ubuntu/niftynet/NiftyNet/niftynet/engine/sampler_uniform.py", line 151, in _spatial_coordinates_generator
    _infer_spatial_size(img_sizes, win_sizes)
  File "/home/ubuntu/niftynet/NiftyNet/niftynet/engine/sampler_uniform.py", line 238, in _infer_spatial_size
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError`

Comment: Welcome! Is this information something that another niftynet user can just plug into the package and run to recreate the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved here: https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/issues/170

In summary images and labels should have the same voxel spacing values stored in their header when `pixdim` is set in the configuration file.